# Implementing K nearest neighbors with caret in R

Tags: r, r-caret, knn

I'm trying to build a basic KNN model for this dataset in R using caret, however it doesn't seem to be working (or maybe it is?) In the confusion matrix at the end it only makes 'no' predictions, no 'yes' ones, which seems wrong. How do you do this properly?

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing

```
> data <- read.csv("bank-additional.csv", sep=";")
> trainIndex <- createDataPartition(data$y, p=0.7, list=FALSE, times=1)
> creditTrain <- data[trainIndex,]
> creditTest <- data[-trainIndex,]
> View(creditTrain)
> View(creditTest)
> scaler <- preProcess(creditTrain, method=c("center", "scale"))
> creditTrain <- predict(scaler, creditTrain)
> creditTest <- predict(scaler, creditTest)
> knnModel <- train(y ~ age + job + education + default, data = data, method="knn")
> creditTestPredictions <- predict(knnModel, creditTest)
> confusionMatrix(creditTestPredictions, creditTest$y)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction   no  yes
       no  1100  135
       yes    0    0

               Accuracy : 0.8907          
                 95% CI : (0.8719, 0.9075)
    No Information Rate : 0.8907          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.5229          

                  Kappa : 0               
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          

            Sensitivity : 1.0000          
            Specificity : 0.0000          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.8907          
         Neg Pred Value :    NaN          
             Prevalence : 0.8907          
         Detection Rate : 0.8907          
   Detection Prevalence : 1.0000          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.5000          

       'Positive' Class : no              

>
```

Comment: Here are two nice tutorials on the matter: [mlr](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/over_and_undersampling.html), [caret](https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html). First I would try optimizing hyperparemeter search for kappa or balanced accuracy instead of accuracy while assigning different weights to classes (knn does not support this I trust). Then I would try tuning the threshold and at the very end I would try up/down sampling,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a highly unbalanced dataset so I would not be surprised if your trained algorithm predicts no for all instances.

How to fix it remains to be a nontrivial topic. I can list a few possibilities. The most common one is to use cross-validation. It may not always works, but does not hurt to try. Or you can use some penalization to adjust your optimization goal, currently you are only optimizing the accuracy. Third, you can upsample the underrepresented class until balanced.